# How to find all domains containing specific string

Tags: search, domain, search-engines

I want to know which different `pedia`'s exist.

I want a list of all registered domains, which end with `pedia.org`, `pedia.com` or `pedia.info`, (e.g `WIKIpedia.org` or `Anotherpedia.info`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to achieve that using an existing search engine, you can use *[Google's Search Engine Operators](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861)*, which can be very powerful:

---

[This search query](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=%22pedia.org%22+OR+%22pedia.com%22+OR+%22pedia.info%22&oq=%22pedia.org%22+OR+%22pedia.com%22+OR+%22pedia.info%22&gs_l=serp.3...36950.38208.0.38338.3.2.1.0.0.0.262.422.0j1j1.2.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1j2.3XD-viMtD2k) will give you a list of all registered domains
ending with `pedia.org`, `pedia.com` or `pedia.info` (it's not as powerful as the second search query, because it's limited - but that's what you've asked for):

```
"pedia.org" OR "pedia.com" OR "pedia.info"
```

Search Operators used:

- **Quotes:**  *Search for an exact word or phrase:* `"search query"`
- **OR operator:** *Search for either word:* `query OR query`

---

### **EDIT:**

Dave Rook has suggested this search query: `site:*pedia.*`.

The problem with this query is that for some reason, it only lists domains that precede `-` or `.` before `pedia`, as *unor* pointed out. It seems like a bug, and because of that `wikipedia.org` won't show up on the search results.

**However**, there is a another (less popular) search operator that is actually very useful:

- **in:** *Search within URL / page title /  page body / backlinks:*

  `inurl:query intitle:query intext:query inanchor:query`

So if you want a wider search (instead of limiting yourself to `.org`,`.com`,`.info` pedia sites), two very powerful search queries would be:

```
inurl:*"pedia"* intitle:*"pedia"*
inurl:*pedia* intitle:*pedia*
```

<sup>**allin** could be more powerful, but it's not possible to combine it with another search operator, and therefore it's better to use **in** instead.</sup>

Since it looks for `pedia` in both the URL and the title, it will give you only real pedia sites.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for some shell script what print out a list of domains, but the search engine approach is usable, only need more work for digging thru the search result. Accepting. ;)

Comment: @kobame I've added an additional powerful search query, which you might find useful. See my (edited) answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the wild card which is an astrix <kbd>*</kbd> around a query string and the keyword 'site:' to tell Google you're after a site search. Type the following into Google: (no spaces and exactly as is)

> `site:*pedia.*`

or click this [Google.co.uk](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site:~pedia.~&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=M5z&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:*pedia.*&oq=site:*pedia.*&fp=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&cad=b&sei=UodYUPmVOMOQhQfezYHgAQ) link (which is a shortcut to show Google with the search term above).

However, as you'll see, this will not just do the Wikipedia style sites and doesn't limit you to only .com, .org and .info.

You will also need to note that doing a search on Google.co.uk will possibly provide different results compared Google.com, Google.fr, Google.de etc

> Each * represents just one or more words. Google treats the * as a
>   placeholder for a word or more than one word. For example, [ “Google *
>   my life“ ] tells Google to find pages containing a phrase that starts
>   with “Google” followed by one or more words, followed by “my life.”
>   Phrases that fit the bill include: “Google changed my life,” “Google
>   runs my life,” and “Google is my life.”

[Google's wildchild operator](http://www.googleguide.com/wildcard_operator.html)

Comment: Thank you too (+1), but accepted amiregelz solution because its results are more consistent. With your approach i got more than one results for each found domain e.g. www.energy-pedia.com or soo.

Comment: With this query I don't get wikipedia.org at all. It seems that it only lists domains that precede "`-`" or "`.`" before "`pedia`".

Comment: @unor I have updated my answer with an improved search query, thanks for pointing that out.