# Registered domain 'list'

Tags: dns, domain, registrar

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/476535/how-to-find-all-domains-containing-specific-string) question is similar to what I am wanting, but not quite. I have searched, without even a hint of success, for a way to 'browse' all registered domains by TLD - not just per registrar.

*P.S.: If this is the wrong 'exchange' site, I am sorry and would appreciate it if it could be moved to the right one. I thought this one seemed to be where it fit in best, but I wasn't sure.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up your own DNS server will not help to discover registered domain names.

There is no any way to discover 100% of registered domain names. Even Godaddy can't.

1. For classic/gTLD zones (.com/.net/etc) most of domains can be found in zone files. You can apply to ICAAN, Verisign *or* use domain lists aggregators like zonefiles.io
2. But country-code registrars (.de/.uk/.fr/.tr/etc) never discover their zone files to any 3rd parties. That means that no one can provide complete lists of all country-code domains.

Nevertheless, you can again use domain likes aggregators (and get 85-90% of domain base). Some of them combine domain lists from original zone files with their own data (they built web crawlers that scan the entire internet for country-code domain names - much like search engines do).

Currently this is the easiest way to get lists of domain names. As mentioned above, 100% coverage is not technically possible.

Comment: I thought this question died. This is very helpful. In my case, I only had 4 gTLDs that I was needing to list, but it does suck that country code TLDs aren't possible.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who used to work for one of the largest domain name registrars, I am not aware of any registry providing a method to search their databases to get a complete list of domain names that are currently registered for that TLD.

Comment: Do you know whether it would be possible to list all domains registered? If I could do that I could scrape them and filter them with a small PHP script...

Comment: I just had an epiphany on how this could be done. Except, I have no clue how to do it. Setup a DNS server, sync it, and dump it's database. The all you have to do is sort it and ditch the info you don't want.